# Not able to access ContainerView from a childView in init() method

Tags: ember.js

I have different `childViews` of a `ContainerView`. Is it possible to access `ContainerView` from `childView` in `init()` method. I have tried using `this.get('parentView')` which doesnot work in `init()` method

Comment: Did you call this._super() before trying to access the parentView ?

Comment: yes..i called and tested it..not working...

Comment: wow, definitely need more code in order to go further

Answer (score 1):

It should be available as `this._parentView` in `init` of the child view.

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/6p6XJ/192/

Comment: do i need to set autoinit to false in application??..coz when i dont its not running..check this http://jsfiddle.net/codejack/rqdSH/2/

Comment: Yes, in the JSFiddle environment, you need `autoinit: false`.

Comment: ok...here is how am trying to do..am pushing a childView in init() method. This way its not working...http://jsfiddle.net/codejack/7TueU/1/

Comment: @CodeJack, you are trying to push a view class into `childViews` but at init, `childViews` is designed to contain instantiated views. The syntax that allows you to use strings that point to properties of the container view that are set to view classes is a shortcut that works at class definition time, but not at runtime.